# Why select cannot be disabled/enabled in jquery mobile multi pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile, select

I have a mobile application which uses the multi-page template. In this application, I want to disable a select when the page is loaded and then enable it after a radio button is clicked. I've seen a strange thing: the disable/enable works (except its style) if the select is put on page 1 but it doesn't work if is put on other pages.

The following is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Multi-page template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="mb.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<!-- Start of first page: #page1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Test </h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content" >  
<p>This is page One</p>
<form name="formC" id="formC"  >        
<label for="city">CITY: </label>                
<select id="city" name="city" >
<option value="1">Sydney</option>
<option value="2">North Ryde</option>
<option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
Operations:
<input id="radioC1" name="city_type" type="radio"  value="NO" >
<label for="radioC1"> 1 Disable city menu </label>
<input id="radioC2" name="city_type" type="radio" value="YES">
<label for="radioC2"> 2 Enable city menu </label>                 
</form>
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
<a data-role="button" href="#page1" > Page 1 </a>        
<a data-role="button" href="#page2" > Page 2 </a>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page one -->

<!-- Start of second page: #page2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Test</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">   
<p>This is page Two</p>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
<a data-role="button" href="#page1" > Page 1 </a>        
<a data-role="button" href="#page2" > Page 2 </a>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page two -->

</body>
</html>
```

The code of the javaScript mb.js is shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#city").prop("disabled", true);
  $('input:radio[name="city_type"]').change (
  function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'YES') {
    //  alert("Click city_type, Enable");
    $("#city").removeAttr('disabled');  
        // append goes here
    } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'NO') {
    //    alert("Click city_type, Disable");
    $("#city").prop("disabled", true);      
        // append goes here
    }
  });
});
```

As seen from the code, the form which contains a select with id 'city' is put on page 1. In this case, the select is disabled at the beginning although its style still looks like enabled. I can enable/disable it by clicking the radio buttons. However after I've moved the form into page 2 from page 1, the select doesn't work! Although it is disabled at the beginning, I am not able to enable/disable it by clicking the radio buttons.

Really I don't know why. I have tried to use different versions of jquery and css but could not fix the problem. Is it a bug in jquery mobile multi-pages? Appreciated if some one can help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems - without looking extremely close at your code, I notice that you're using `$(document).ready()` but you should be using:

```
$(document).delegate("#MyPageId", "pagebeforecreate", function () {
});
```

and

```
$(document).delegate("#MyPageId", "pageshow", function () {
})
```

instead. ( http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-equivalent-of-document-ready )

Try moving your code into those areas and you'll have some success :)